How to carry out Dunnett's post hoc correction on a 2-way ANOVA in R?
How can I perform Dunnett's post hoc correction after a 2-way ANOVA in R?
The Dunnett's test compares every mean to a control mean. Using ToothGrowth dataset as an example, lets just say that that dose=0.5 and supp=VC is the control group.
If I carry out a 2-way ANOVA
model <- aov(len~supp*dose,data = ToothGrowth) 
How do I carry out Dunnett's post hoc correction?
DunnettTest from the PMCMRplus and DescTools packages only seem to work with 1-way ANOVA, as far as I can tell.
